# Mapping components dynamically using webpack in Next.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js, strapi

I'm building a NextJS app which fetches data from a strapi CMS at build time. Strapi allows to organize content using components and I would like to map strapi components to the ones of my Next project in order to build each web page according to the data fetched from strapi.

I would like, though, to keep my code clean and export a variable named `strapiComponentId` from each module that also exports a component (as a default export) in order to construct my component mapping at build time.

I was able to achieve this by using webpack's `require.context`, inspecting all the modules inside the `components` directory storing in an object all the ones that export a `strapiComponentId` variable. The code is following:

```js
const req = require.context("@/components", false, /components.*\.js$/);

const mapping = req.keys().reduce((acc, current) => {
  const componentModule = req(current);
  if (componentModule.strapiComponentId != undefined) {
    acc[componentModule.strapiComponentId] = componentModule.default;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
```

This way I have a map that, given a strapi component id (which is part of the strapi response), returns the related component. The code does not handle errors but works for testing purposes.

In order for the `req(current)` function to return an object instead of a promise I had to set `experimental: { esmExternals: false }` in `next.config.js`, as stated **[here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/42931)**.

My **question** is, then, the following:

Is there better solution in order to achieve the same result (maybe using `next/dynamic` feature)? If not, which are the side effects caused by disabling `esmExternals`?

Thank you for your time.